# How do you move an ActiveStorage::Attached::One to an ActiveStorage::Attached::Many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have two fields on a model called Project:

```
has_one_attached :image
has_many_attached :assets
```

I want to move the image to the assets so I can get rid of the has_one_attached :image.

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question but thought it would be useful to share:

```
p = Project.find(id)
p.assets.attach(p.image.blob)
p.image.detach
```

This successfully removed the image and moved it to assets.